# C++ comparing two value to find which is closest to user input value

Tags: c++

I have been looking on the internets for a while to find a solution to my problem.  First some back ground.  I'm writing a program that calculates catapult trajectory.  The user must first type in a distance. Then I loop through the combinations of angle degrees and velocity to find which combination will give a distance that will come the closest to the users input.  I don't quite know how to do the variable comparison to find which combination of degrees and velocity produces a distance closest to a users input of distance.  I'm just trying to keep it simple and easy as possible.  Also, I'm not using any kind of array to store the values. I want it done on the fly inside my for loops if possible.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is this your homework assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer to this depends on the complexity of your trajectory formula.  I'm guessing that you're not taking fluid dynamics or gravity differentials into consideration.  In fact, what I imagine is that you're using a basic parabolic equation...

That equation can be solved directly by rearranging.  But the thing is, you're solving for two variables that are actually co-dependent.  There are infinite solutions if you allow both angle and velocity to vary, so you need to restrict the 'best' answer by some criteria (for example, desired angle or desired velocity).

If you have more variables, like lift, drag, spin, incident shape, non-constant gravity, air pressure and humidity, then you will need to employ a minimization algorithm which is non-trivial.  One of the most basic, but a little unstable, is the Nelder-Mead algorithm.

If this has not been helpful enough, you should provide more information about your problem, and show some code.

Comment: I'm not taking any outside factors into account, and I'm using a simple parabola equation to find the distance. the user can pick a distance between 500 and 10000. the angle degree is between 1 and 89, and velocity is between 50 and 500. the problem is I don't quite know of a way to logically test the answers to find which one is closest.  Generally the must be a way to test if x or y is closer to b.